# Will the transaction cancel the action in the methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework

what will happen if during a transaction I call one method it will be executed correctly then during the same transaction I call another method but it will give an error at this time transaction.Rollback () undo everything that was done in the methods

Here is my code snippet

> MyService Code

```
public class MyService
{
    public void UpdateProduct(int product, decimal amount)
    {
        var db = new MyContext();

        var product = db.Products.Find(product);

        var productLog = new ProductLog();
        productLog.ProductID = product.ProductID;
        productLog.OldAmount = product.Amount;

        product.Amount -= amount;

        productLog.NewAmount = product.Amount;

        db.ProductLogs.Add(productLog);
        db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void AddOrder(Order order)
    {
        var db = new MyContext();

        db.Orders.Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

> MainCode

```
        public void SetOrders(Order order)
        {
            var db = new MyContext();

            using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var service = new MyService();

                    service.AddOrder(order);
                    service.UpdateProduct(order.ProductID, order.Amount);

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I initially closed this question as a duplicate and voted to reopen that one, though thinking about it, it seems better that you **delete your original question** and just leave this one. As such, I've reopened this question.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with EF, but since you're using a completely different context for accessing the database, I would expect the transaction to have no bearing on the other methods, which each use their own contexts. I might be wrong about that, so hopefully someone more knowledgable can jump in and answer.

Comment: Cross-context transactions [are possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#cross-context-transaction) in EF Core, provided the contexts share both a DbConnection and a DbTransaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to orchestrate a transaction across two services (which you should do), you should inject the same DbContext into both services, instead of creating a seperate DbContext in each one.  ASP.NET Core DI does this for you when you register your DbContext with [AddDbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-5.0).

So MyService should have a constructor that takes an instance of your DbContext, then you pass your single DbContext to the service:

```
    public void SetOrders(Order order)
    {
        var db = new MyContext();

        using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                var service = new MyService(db);

                service.AddOrder(order);
                service.UpdateProduct(order.ProductID, order.Amount);

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw; //<don't swallow exceptions!!!
            }
        }
    }
```